# ModelState.AddModelError encodes HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am noticing a weird issue when using ModelState.AddModelError to validate input on my forms. The output from Html.ValidationMessage is not the true HTML value but it's encoded value and so the CSS style is not applied to the error message.

Example:

```
private string errorMessage = "<span class=\"negative\">{0}</span><br class=\"hid\" />";
ModelState.AddModelError("title", String.Format(errorMessage, "Tab title is required"));
```

The output is shown as:

```
<span class="field-validation-error">&lt;span class=&quot;negative&quot;&gt;URL is Required&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br class=&quot;hid&quot; /&gt;</span>
```

This didn't use to be the case with their earlier beta's and I am not sure what approach to take here.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is another way to do it, too, without having to create your own extension.

Say for instance we have the following in one of our controllers:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "<b>Please Use a Valid Person Name</b>");
```

We can then do the following in our view:

```
@if(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name) != null){
    @Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name).ToString())
}
```

The will prevent the error message of `'<b>Please Use a Valid Person Name</b>'` from being encoded.

Comment: I do not know if this worked at one time, but I can confirm that it doesn't in MVC 3.

Comment: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(x =>    x.Name).ToHtmlString()));

Answer (score 1):

Create your own extension method that mimics Html.VallidationMessage...?

I had to do something similar because the built in MVC validation stuff (ModelState, ValidationMessage etc etc) doesn't cater for pages that have more than one form on a page.

Comment: you're right - i had updated the wrong item. They were both related to encoding of the html - i just had updated the wrong one. I've removed the update. thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of several changes in .NET, we query ModelState values for errors using the relevant key. Using this approach you don't have to decode any string you pass using `ModelState.AddModelError`

```
@{
    var state = ModelState.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("title"));
    var error = state.Value != null &&
        state.Value.Errors.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ErrorMessage))
        ? state.Value.Errors.LastOrDefault()
        : null;
}
@if (error != null)
{
    <span>@Html.Raw(error.ErrorMessage)</span>
}
```

Here is an extension for the same

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

public static class ModelStateDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static string GetError(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, string key)
    {
        var state = modelState.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(key));
        var error = state.Value != null && 
            state.Value.Errors.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ErrorMessage))
            ? state.Value.Errors.LastOrDefault()
            : null;
        return error?.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

The usage would be:

```
@{
    var errorTitle = ModelState.GetError("title");
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorTitle))
{
    <span>@Html.Raw(errorTitle)</span>
}
```