# how to add html into a modelstate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 to build and application.
I have a validation summary that captures errors on a form submit.

I am adding errors like this

```
ModelState.AddErrors("error 1")
```

which works great,

But i want to be able to add the following

```
ModelState.AddErrors("<button>Test</button>")
```

This just spits out the HTML as text, not as a buuton.  How can i show html elements in the validation summary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To output the html and render the button in your ModelState errors, specify a key

```
ModelState.AddErrors("testButton", "<button>Test</button>");
```

Now, you can use the following code:

```
@{
    var state = ModelState.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals("testButton"));
    var error = state.Value != null &&
        state.Value.Errors.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ErrorMessage))
        ? state.Value.Errors.LastOrDefault()
        : null;
}
@if (error != null)
{
    @Html.Raw(error.ErrorMessage)
}
```

Here, you set a key (e.g. "testButton") and query the ModelState Value using the key. Finally, you locate any errors present in the key and display the output if any.

We use `Html.Raw()` to parse and return the Html markup present in the error message.

Comment: Worked for me. great! An extension implementation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method like this:

```
public static HtmlString ToHtmlString(this String str)
{
    return new HtmlString(str);
}
```

Then in your view, call your validation summary like this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary().ToString().ToHtmlString()
```

Comment: That will not compile, and won't help either.

Comment: I have typed the following,  @Html.ValidationSummary(Strings.Edit_Was_Unsuccessful, new { id = "edit_form_error" }).ToString().ToHtmlString() it says {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Answer (score -1):

As per this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727160/modelstate-addmodelerror-encodes-html) answer given by [roshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019019/roshan)

Controller

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "<button>Test</button>");
```

View

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(false).ToHtmlString()))
```

Comment: I want it for the validation summary

Comment: it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I have tried it is working fine... try to add error like this `ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "<button>Test</button>");` not `ModelState.AddErrors("<button>Test</button>")`