# Change Encoding in ModelState.ModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, modelstate, addmodelerror

Here is my problem: I add a message to ModelError with `addModelError(String.Empty,”My message”)`. 
In my view I just call `@Html.ValidationSummary().`
The message is in German and the characters Ö, Ä, Ü are just shown as questionmark. How do I change that?

Comment: Could you show your web.config?

Comment: check out these SO posts..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638031/how-to-include-a-link-in-addmodelerror-message, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727160/modelstate-addmodelerror-encodes-html

Comment: You can use Globalization . But have you tried with `HTML.Raw()` ?

Comment: Html.Raw does not work. The message gets encoded before send to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it there are two options. One option is to write a custom validation summary helper which doesn't HTML encode the messages like described in the link that Kartikeya Khosla provided. Or, and that’s what I did, Just use the Unicode reference in the message string. The solution in Kartikeya is more elegant, but in my case it is a lot of code to change two characters. By the way here a link to look them up if anybody wants to do the same:

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct&unicodeinhtml=dec&htmlent=1